# Switching heading numbering between sections

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016

I would like to achive the following heading numbering in my document

```
I. Test
II. Test
III. Test
1. Test
2. Test
  2.1. Test
  2.2. Test
3. Test
IV. Test
V. Test
A. Test
  A.1. Test
    A.1.1. Test
  A.2. Test
```

Between each change of heading numbering I inserted a `next page`. Then I created a new list based on the format `Heading 1` and choose `This point forward`. The switch between roman and arabic numbering is working fine but when trying to change back to roman numbering (for `IV.`, `V.`) it will change the numbering of `I.`, `II.` and `III.` back to arabic.

Any way to achive the above numbering with just the Heading format styles?

Comment: I think the only way to set up this heterogenuos numbering is to use section break. You can set up independent styles in different sections.

Comment: well I am doing a section break when choosing `next page` or?

Comment: No, page break doesn't break section. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Insert-a-section-break-eef20fd8-e38c-4ba6-a027-e503bdf8375c

Comment: I am not talking about a `page break`. The `Next Page` option will insert a section break. Thats what your source says as well.